# Is it possible to record MJPEG directly on android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-camera, codec

Is it possible to record video from an android camera directly as MJPEG? I am interested in MJPEG for quality purposes. I don't want to record video via default android settings and then convert to MJPEG, but directly from the camera device as MJPEG. Is this possible? I can't find any information suggesting this is possible.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input -c copy output`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not much to elaborate. `input` is the path the the camera or a pipe. `-c copy` uses [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. `output` is the output. Your question had few details, so I just gave you a basic suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Code in Kotlin.

You just have to get continuous images via setRepeatingRequest on the capture request.
Call takeMJPEG with true to start and false to stop.

Open the resulting file with GOM player. I have tested the implementation.

```
    private val takeMJPEGSemaphore  = Semaphore(1)

    var mjpegBufferStream: BufferedOutputStream? = null
    var mjpegFileStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    var mjpegRecording = false


    override fun takeMJPEG(start: Boolean) {
        Log.i(TAG, "takeMJPEG start:$start")
        if (start) {
            takeMJPEGSemaphore.acquire()
            mjpegRecording = true
            val mjpegOutputFile = createFile(context, "mjpeg")
            mjpegFileStream = FileOutputStream(mjpegOutputFile)
            mjpegBufferStream = BufferedOutputStream(mjpegFileStream)
            // Clear imageReader
            var image: Image? = null
            do {
                image?.close()
                image = imageReader.acquireNextImage()
            } while (image != null)
            session.stopRepeating()
            session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
            var count = 0
            var initialTime: Long = 0
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
                image = reader.acquireNextImage()
                if (count == 0) {
                    initialTime = image!!.timestamp
                }
                count++
                val buffer = image?.planes?.get(0)?.buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer!!.remaining()).apply { buffer.get(this) }
                mjpegBufferStream!!.write(bytes)
                mjpegBufferStream!!.flush()
                if (!mjpegRecording) {
                    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)
                    session.stopRepeating()
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
                    // Save the mjpeg file
                    mjpegBufferStream?.flush()
                    mjpegBufferStream?.close()
                    val finalTime = image!!.timestamp
                    Log.i(TAG, "saved mjpeg file with fps = ${count / ((finalTime - initialTime) / 1000000000.0)}")
                    takeMJPEGSemaphore.release()
                }
                image?.close()
            }, imageReaderHandler)
        } else {
            mjpegRecording = false
            takeMJPEGSemaphore.acquire()
            takeMJPEGSemaphore.release()
        }
    }


        private fun createFile(context: Context, extension: String): File {
            val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera")
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs()
            }
            return File.createTempFile(createFileName(), ".$extension", dir)
        }
        private fun createFileName(): String {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS", Locale.US)
            return "IMG_${sdf.format(Date())}"
        }
```